# Detecting long wait times in the Linux scheduler

Tags: linux, scheduler

I've been trying to find a way to detect when a particular thread is running on a CPU and when it is not. Ideally, I'd like to hook in directly to the kernel to keep track of when my thread is scheduled, when it yields, and when it is interrupted by a context switch. Is there any off the shelf tool that can report this information accurately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want 'perf sched' utility, or if running an older kernel, 'ftrace'.

'perf sched' has five sub-commands currently:

perf sched {record|latency|map|replay|script}

- record  - low-overhead recording of arbitrary workloads
- latency - output per task latency metrics
- map     - show summary/map of context-switching
- replay  - replay a captured workload using simulated threads
- script  - to see a detailed trace of the workload that was recorded

http://lwn.net/Articles/353295/

```
    man perf-sched
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [OProfile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/about/).

That would be the easiest off the shelf way to look at your system performance, and would probably be good enough for what you need.  If you need something else super-custom, then you might end up doing something like building a custom kernel that toggles a GPIO during scheduling events of interest, and looking at the signal with a logic analyzer.  I don't recommend that approach because it won't be worth your time.

Comment: Also adding additional logic to the scheduling code in the kernel is likely to skew results especially since it is called ALOT :)